# Applying new buttons to the game

Tags: javascript, html, button

In a game text adventure I am making with my friend, once a player goes through a certain path, he/she finds a stick and some rocks during the way.

When you find these rocks and sticks, I would like to add 2 buttons to appear under that statement, saying: `"Grab the sticks and rocks"`.

Then, another button next to it saying `"Leave it there"`. However, I am having some trouble doing this and would like to have some help.
Still very confused on how to apply these new buttons under..

Here is the current Javascript code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
  var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>';
  var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
  var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
  myButton.onclick = four;
}

function two()
{
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for  
something."; 
  document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function three()
{
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.";
  document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four()
{
  document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="You feel a stick stuck to the wall with something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.";
}
</script>
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
  <button id="btnOne" onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:255px; width:200px; margin-top:-15px;">
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px;height:600px;"> 
  <div id="d"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I'm actually facing is after the "Find rocks" statement, I want to add 2 buttons underneath the statement saying "Grab the rocks and sticks" and another saying "Leave it there". I'll like some help with that part.

Comment: `after the "Find rocks" statement` ??? where?

Answer (score 2):

**From what i understood, use this Javascript code:**

```
function one()
{
  var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>';
  var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
  var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
  myButton.onclick = four;
}

function two()
{
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for  
something."; 
  document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';

}

function three()
{
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue 
on.";
  document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four()
{
  var newButton1 = '<button id="btnFour" onclick="five()" >Grab the sticks and rocks</button>';
  var newButton2 = '<button id="btnFive" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
  document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="You feel a stick stuck to the wall with something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.";
}

function five()
{
  document.getElementById("e").innerHTML="You did grab the sticks and rocks. It might be useful for something.";
  document.getElementById("btnFour").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnFive").style.display = 'none';
}

function six()
{
  document.getElementById("f").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue 
on.";
  document.getElementById("btnFour").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btnFive").style.display = 'none';
}
```

and use this `entire` div:

```
<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px;  height:600px;"> 
  <div id="f"></div>
  <div id="e"></div>
  <div id="d"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Note, that i added 2 divs to the HTML, div `f` and div `e` and on the javascript i added two functions, the function `five()` and the function `six()`.

Comment: Thanks Paulo Roberto, however the code doesn't function the way I'll like it to?

Comment: whats the way you like to? explain, explain more what do you want boy.

Comment: I'll like those two boxes to come after the "honey" statement. I've tried your code however it is not working for me...